# What Is Needed To Use fopen() On An Embedded System?

Tags: c, file, embedded, fopen

I am quite new to the FILE family of functions that the standard C library provides.

I recently stumbled across `fopen()` and the similar functions after researching how `stdout`, `stdin` and `stderr` work alongside functions like `printf()`.

I was wondering, what is needed to use `fopen()` on an embedded system (which doesn't necessarily have operating system support). After reading more about it, is seems like a cool thing to do on more powerful embedded systems to hook into say, a UART/SPI interface, so that calling `printf()` would print data out of the UART. Simarly, you could read data from a UART buffer by calling `scanf()`.

This would also increase portability! (code written for say, Linux, would be easier to port if `printf()` was supported). You could also print debug data to a file if it was running in a production environment, and read from it later.

Can you just use `fopen()` on a bare-bones embedded system? If so who/where/when is the "FILE" then created (as far as I now, `fopen()` does not `malloc()` space for the file, nor do you specify how much)? Or do you need a operating system with FAT file support. If so, would something like http://ultra-embedded.com/?fat_filelib work? Would using FreeRTOS help at all?

Comment: @dwelch I had a look (downloaded the CVS repo, searched and found the fopen() function), but it didn't really help answer the question.

Comment: everything you said about fopen being cool, doesnt necessarily have operating system support, even better a printf and scanf tied to a uart, that is exactly a description of newlib.  fopen() is really not the key to it at all.  syscalls.c and libcfunc.c are where all the magic is.  And if you are using CVS you are probably looking at the wrong newlib.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the documentation for your toolchain's C library - it should have something to say about re-targeting the library.

For example if you are using [Newlib](http://www.sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Syscalls) you must re-implement some or all of the [syscalls stubs][3] to suit your target.  The low level `open()` syscall in this case will allow `fopen()` to work as necessary.  At its simplest, you might implement `open()` to support higher-level stdio access to serial ports, but if you are expecting standard file-system access, then you will still need an underlying file-system to map it too.

Another example of re-targeting the Keil/ARM standard library can be found [here](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/gsac/gsac_retargetcortex.htm).

Comment: +1 for "check the documentation for your toolchain's C library".  I have found this exercise to be very dependent on the compiler vendor's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's often possible to use `fopen()` and similar routines in code for embedded systems.  The way it often works is that the vendor supplies a C compiler and associated libraries
targeted for their system, which implement some supported subset of the language in a way that's appropriate for that system (e.g. an implementation of `printf()` that outputs via a UART, or `fopen()` that uses RAM to simulate some sort of filesystem).

Comment: So `fopen()` could be using `malloc()` to create space for this file on the heap? How would it determine the file size in this case, surely it wouldn't re-call `malloc()` everytime a byte is written to the file?

Comment: @gbmhunter:  Not necessarily malloc()...there could be a fixed area of physical memory dedicated to the in-memory filesystem.  The stdio library routines for such a platform would implement calls like fopen, fread, fwrite, etc. as RAM allocations/reads/writes.  And it would probably be in units of blocks, rather than bytes, just like you'd expect to see in a disk-based filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

On the Keil compiler, the `stdio` library is designed to allow the user to define the `__FILE` structure in any desired fashion.  A function like `fprintf` will perform a sequence of calls to `fputc`, which will receive a copy of the pointer passed to `fprintf`.  One may define something like `fopen` to "create" a `__FILE` and populate its members via any desired means (if there will never be more than one file open at a time, one could simply fill in the fields of a static instance and return that).  Variables `__stdin`, `__stdout`, and `__stderror` may likewise be defined as desired (`stdin` is defined to point to `__stdin`, and likewise with `stdout` and `stderror`).

Answer (score 0):

"Can you just use fopen() on a bare-bones embedded system?"
It depends. Depends on the configuration of your embedded system, the types of memories interfaced, on what memory do you want to implement the file system, the file system library code size (ROM & RAM requirements). 
FILE manipulation functions can be used independent of any OS. But a proper file system must be used and FAT is not the only file system (JFFS2, YAFS,...some other proprietary file system) 
The file system is generally (but not always) implemented on Flash memories (Nand Flash, Nor Flash). USB device is also a flash (Nand flash). The Nand Flash & Nor Flash may have Parallel interface, I2C interface or SPI interface.